# Does the GC collect an object with no reference variable, even if the object is stored in a HashMap with an id key?

Tags: java

Consider the following:
I'm creating a new instances of a class and putting them inside a HashMap with unique keys. For every new instance, the reference variable stays the same (i.e. just points to the new object instead of the old one). 
My question is: Does the keys serve as a good enough reference so that the GC doesn't collect the objects with no reference variables, inside the HashMap? Or maybe the HashMap reference is enough, so the objects inside are safe from the GC? When does the GC collect in this case?

Comment: If it is stored in a `HashMap` then the object has a reference (as long as you have a reference to the `HashMap`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: no, it won't be collected.

Longer answer: as long as the object is strongly reachable, it will not be collected. It doesn't matter if it's reachable only indirectly (via the `HashMap`).